# How do I find the correct key in my Info.plist file for a file uploader with a file picker in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, info.plist

I'm currently working on an iOS app and trying to implement a file uploader that allows the user to select and upload files. I've already integrated a file picker dialog into my user interface, but I'm having trouble adding the necessary permissions in my Info.plist file.

What key should be present in my Info.plist file to ensure that my app has the necessary permissions to access the file picker dialog?

I've already looked through the documentation, but I'm not sure which key is specific to this purpose.

I appreciate any help!